# Fast date entry in ms access forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple database in which I enter my daily transactions in a table through a form called [Account Transactions List]. I do not enter all of the transactions on the actual day that they happened. I rather sit down and enter all of the dates for one week at a time. Therefore, I need to manually adjust the date field to match the actual transaction date. Rather than type the whole date each time, I like to use shortcut keys.

I have used Quickbooks some in my life. In Quickbooks you can use the "+", "-", and other keys to quickly manipulate the date. For example "+" advances the date by 1 day, while "-" subtracts one day from the date. "y" takes you to the first day of the year, while "r" takes you to the last day of the year. There are others, but this gives you an idea. I am trying to replicate this in my access form. Here is the code that I have on my Date control in the On Key Down event.

```
Private Sub Entry_Date_Keydown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
Dim dte As Date

Select Case KeyCode
    Case 189, 109 'Minus key '-'
    KeyCode = 0
    'subtract one day from current date
    Me.Entry_Date = Me.Entry_Date - 1
    SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
    Me.Dirty = False
    Case 187, 107 '= key (used for the plus)
    KeyCode = 0
    'add one day to current date
    Me.Entry_Date = Me.Entry_Date + 1
    SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
    Case 84 ' T key
    KeyCode = 0
    Me.Entry_Date = Now
    SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
    'Let any other key press go
    Case Else
    KeyCode = KeyCode

End Select

End Sub
```

This works well for the most part. Occasionally, though, it turns the num lock off. I cannot figure out a pattern as to why or when it does so. Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not. Maybe it has to do with the number of times I press the shortcut. This is quite annoying for efficient data entry as the second from the next control is a number control. I believe that it has to do with the `SendKeys`, but cannot understand how to avoid them. The `SendKeys` help to update the control between each key press so that you can see the date update as you press the shortcut keys. Otherwise, the date control only updates on exit.

Can I verify if NUM LOCK is off or on at the end of each key press or on exit control and turn it back on?

OR

Avoid the use of `SendKeys` in this instance? (Since I believe that this is causing the problem)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*SendKeys* is for sure the key (pun intended) to your trouble.

Instead of manipulating the interface, address the *RecordsetClone* of the form. This way, you can both edit and save the data easily.

Also, you could perhaps optimise the interface for speedy entering of dates as described in my article:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

*(If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article)*

Code is too much to post here, but you may be able to modify it to accept your shortcuts. Full code is at any time at **GitHub**: [VBA.DateEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DateEntry)

**Addendum**:

By second thought, I think this is all you need - no SendKeys:

```vb
Private Sub Entry_Date_Keydown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 189, 109       ' Minus key '-'
            ' Subtract one day from current date.
            Me!Entry_Date.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Me!Entry_Date.Value)
            KeyCode = 0
        Case 187, 107       ' Plus key '+'
            ' Add one day to current date.
            Me!Entry_Date.Value = DateAdd("d", 1, Me!Entry_Date.Value)
            KeyCode = 0
        Case 84             ' T key
            ' Enter today.
            Me!Entry_Date.Value = Now
            KeyCode = 0
        Case Else
            ' Let any other key press go.
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thank you. This will take me some time to wade through, as I am not an experienced user. But at first glance, I think that it will help me a lot. I'll be back...

Comment: Sorry, to bring this one up again. How would I address the RecordsetClone as you say to change the date with the keys. I imagine it would still be on the KeyDown event. What is better about the Recordset clone? And how do I open a RecordsetClone? Thank you

Comment: I don't think it is needed here. See extended answer, please.

Comment: The reason that I use sendkeys is to show the value between every number press. Otherwise it is only shown on exiting the control. Your code does not seem to do this unless I add sendkeys "{escape}". Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I've corrected the code for typos. But it does show the added/subtracted date value instantly after the key press.

Comment: Then I wonder what setting or property is improperly set in my application, because it does not do that for me. It simply shows the "+" or "-" in the control until I hit escape at which point it shows the original date minus or plus however many times I have pressed.

Comment: It seems as if it is still entering something even though we have entered `keycode = 0`.

Comment: Can't tell. It runs perfectly as intended both for a bound and an unbound textbox. So, double-check your code as there is no way `+` and  `-` should slip through - and/or remove any other code bit by bit until success.

Comment: I have no idea why `keycode = 0` does not work on the KeyDown event. I have found a solution with KeyPress event, instead. I will post it here.

Comment: I thank you, Gustav, for your help. I also appreciate your code for date handling. I have not got up using it in my application yet, since I am the only user so far it has worked. Should I ever need to distribute it to others, I am sure that I will need to use your code to normalize the date entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub EntryDate_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 45       ' Minus key '-'
            KeyAscii = 0
            ' Subtract one day from current date.
            Me!EntryDate.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Me!EntryDate.Value)
        Case 43, 61       ' Plus key '+'
            KeyAscii = 0
            ' Add one day to current date.
            Me!EntryDate.Value = DateAdd("d", 1, Me!EntryDate.Value)
        Case 116             ' T key
            KeyAscii = 0
            ' Enter today.
            Me!EntryDate.Value = Now
        Case Else
            ' Let any other key press go.
    End Select

End Sub
```